# using Multiple header in react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, history, browser-history

```
class App extends Component {
  render() { 
    let pathName=window.location.pathname;
    console.log('pathName==>',pathName);
    let loginhideheaderpath = pathName==="/" || pathName==="/login";
    let securnetheaderpath = pathName==='/Contentlanding/Reports';
    let gallerypath = pathName==='/Contentlanding/Gallerylanding'

    return (  
      <>   
      { securnetheaderpath ? <Securnetheader  /> : ( loginhideheaderpath) ? null :(gallerypath) ? <Galleryheading /> : <Header />   }
       <Router history={history}>
         <Switch>
           <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
           <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
           <Route exact path="/Contentlanding" component={Contentlanding} />            
           <Route exact path="/Contentlanding/Birthdaylist" component={Birthdaylist} />
           <Route exact path="/Contentlanding/Reports" component={Reports} />
           <Route exact path="/Contentlanding/Gallerylanding" component={Gallerylanding} />
           <Route component={Nodocumentfound} />
         </Switch>
       </Router>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

In my project i am using mutiple headers, i am rendering the header for components based on URL.
my condition is working fine. the problem is when i use the browser back button the header are not changing. any solution to fix this Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try movind your headers under the `Router`.

Comment: i have checked with that solution but no use @ravibagul91

Comment: Might be the issue with your nested ternary. Can you provide the codepen?

Comment: nested ternary operator is proper. as per the URL i am getting the required header component. the problem is with browser back button. sorry i am able to update code in codepen or codesandbox @ravibagul91